# Transitive topological action

Tags: general-topology, lie-groups, topological-groups

> Let $G$ be a topological group, $A$ be set and $\mu\colon G\times A\to A$ a transitive action.

I'm trying to prove the statement below is false.

> There exists only one topology in $A$ such that $\mu$ is a continuous function.

I believe the statement is false because there is **more than one** such topology. Alas I'm unable to find a counterexample.

How can I find the appropiate topologies to show the statement is false?

Comment: Which topologies have you tried so far?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I tried the topology given by $\mu$ And the discrete one...

Comment: If you equip $A$ with the trivial topology $\tau=\{\emptyset,A\}$, $\mu$ is continuous. So, if $\mu$ is also continuous for some nontrivial topology on $A$, there are at least two such topologies.